# Prevent g++ adding extra elf sections

Tags: c++, g++, elf, objcopy

When compiling with g++ it creates an extra section for almost each function. 
This occurs on `linux` with `elf64` executable.
By example:

```
text._ZN12MemoryMapper11SetUpMemoryEP11KernelStart
```

How can I tell g++ to emit all code on .text so there is only one .text section

This happens with out the -ffunction-sections

And the sections stay even after

```
objcopy -S file.elf striped
```

==================================================

Extra information:

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -O0 -ffreestanding -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -std=c++11 $(INCLUDES)
g++ version = gcc (GCC) 5.1.0
```

Comment: What happens if you leave out `-g` (don't add debug symbols)?

Answer (score 3):

> `text._ZN12MemoryMapper11SetUpMemoryEP11KernelStart`

This is an *inline* function with [vague linkage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html).

You can avoid creating such sections for inline functions by not having any inline functions in your source. There might be an option to disable generating code for inline functions, but I didn't find one.

Note that disabling this is generally a waste of time: they don't hurt anything, and are required if you have multiple compilation units, or you'll get either link errors, or binary bloat.